# Can dolphindb write and query data at the same time by invoking python api?

Tags: python, sql, dolphindb

Can dolphindb write and query data at the same time by invoking python api?

By invoking dolphindb's python api, Can it write and query data at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The python api of dolphindb supports multiple threads to write data and check data at the same time, but you must avoid writing data to the same partition at the same time, otherwise an error will be reported.